# Angular8 How to load resource inside a sub project assets folder in a good practice way?

Tags: html, angular, angular8, project-structure

I'm working with angular 8, I created a sub-project inside the main project. The folder structure looks like the screenshot:
[image: project structure. ignored unnecessary folders]

Now I'm working on my sub-proj01, and I want to use an "img" tag to import an xxx.svg file inside the sub-proj01's assets folder.

I tried

```html
<img src="assets/xxx.svg">
```

, but I got 404 after I run ng serve in the aggregator folder.

and I tried

```html
<img src="projects/sub-proj01/src/assets/xxx.svg">
```

but I got 404 as well.

So could anybody give me some suggestion that how can I get this? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you including `projects/sub-proj01/src/assets` folder in the `angular.json` file in the `assets` section? By doing so, you should be able to access it like this `<img src="assets/xxx.svg">`

Comment: Hi David, yes, I generated my sub proj with the angular cli, it will auto generate the angular.json.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed, you are missing a slash before `assets/xxx.svg`, it should be `/assets/xxx.svg` assuming in your `index.html` you have your base at `"/"`

Comment: thank you! I did it in a work around way. I created a folder called sub-proj under the aggregator assets folder. I'm trying to make my project with microservice style, but it seems like it not so easy...

Comment: But appreciate if anybody knows a better solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go do angular.json file and in the array called "assets" you will put a object with "glob" that define what you wend copy, "input" that define the path of your subproject assets,  and output" that is the final destine to copy everting.

```
 "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/favicon.png",
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "**/*", //COPY ALL THINGS
            "input": "projects/subproject-name/src/assets", //OF THIS DIRECTORY
            "output": "/assets/" //TO THIS DIRECTORE ROOT
          }
        ],
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, without throwing errors.